# sharepoint table jumps when choosing a status

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a sharepoint page for invoices with different columns. One of my fields is an "action" field. In this field we can "reject, approve or question" an invoice. Now, when I choose one of these options, my table directly jumps as far right as is possible in here. Since this is a table with many columns, this is a bit frustrating while working. Has anyone an idea to fix this?

I searched on here/google  but did not find a sufficient answer. Microsoft also is not responding.

Comment: What is the type of "action" field?